# How do you make .sh or .bash files open with Windows Terminal Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I really like coding in bash, but there used to be many limitations of bash functionality in Windows. Though now there are many benefits to the bash windows users now rather than how it was pre windows 10. However, with all of the improvements, there is one thing that I feel leaves to be desired for me. The default behavior of the double-click of `.sh` files never really was able to do anything in windows, the `.sh` file extension isn't even available in the "choose default apps by file type" section of the settings. I had a desire to be able to change the default action for `.sh` files but neglected it and shook it off for a while, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191386/how-can-i-get-batch-files-to-run-through-the-new-windows-terminal) link finally gave me hope.

---

Before Ubuntu terminal and the addition of Windows subsystem for Linux, there was really no way to access bash terminal on Windows without a VM. Now with the addition of Windows Terminal which combines Microsoft Azure Terminal, Command Prompt, Powershell, and Ubuntu, it is really awesome for people like me, but despite the new awesome additions to windows allowing further integration of Linux terminal into Windows, even being able to edit the `C:` drive with Ubuntu.

I am sure there is a way to allow double-click of `.sh` files to open in windows terminal Ubuntu, but I don't know how. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191386/how-can-i-get-batch-files-to-run-through-the-new-windows-terminal) question helped me on my journey to figure out how to do it and helped me make the default `.bat` file behavior change to Windows terminal, but I still have come to an enpass where I truly believe that it is not possible. So here is where I go when I have given up, the magical land of Stack Overflow :)

---

### Attempts

1. So far I have looked into the *"Choose default apps by file extension"* section of settings and could not find `.sh` in there nor could I find it in any of the default apps sections of normal settings.
2. After I couldn't find anything about `.sh` in settings, I looked into the registry and looked for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and looked for `sh` or anything bash file related in `HCR` alone, `HCR\*\shell`, `HCR\*\shellx`, and `HCR\*\Openwithlist` and could not find anything.
3. I then tried to do `ftype`, but I could not find how to use `ftype` with `.sh`. I tried doing `ftype .sh="C:\Users\asian\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" -p "Ubuntu" "%1" %*` but i got the error "`File type '.sh' not found or no open command associated with it.`"
4. I Also tried just clicking the `.sh` file so it brings up the "How do you want to open this file" menu and went to Windows Terminal but it opened the bash file in powershell with the error `` [error 0x800700c1 when launching `C:\Users\asian\Desktop\test.sh'] ``

   ---

   These where everything I could think of and none of it was working. Help and pointers are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would just like to say, you may be more successful getting answers on superuser/ask ubuntu, which you will not need to create an account for because you can use your stack overflow (also known as stack exchange) account for those sites.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will post this on Super User then

Comment: Actually I don'nt know if it helps, but the git-bash environment which ships with git for Windows automatically assigns .sh files to run with git bash. Perhaps you can look at their implementation how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install the [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) package, as it comes with a light-weight bash environment. This is likely to be able to be in the list of available apps when right-click -> Properties on a `.sh` or `.bash` file and say `Open With` and click the `Change` button next to `Open With`.

Other options are Cygwin or WSL for a 95% pure Linux environment on Windows.