# How do I make it so that double-clicking a ps1 file opens powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to be able to double click a powershell script and it to open in powershell instead of notepad. Can I do that?

To run powershell scripts from the file you right-click the script then click run with powershell, can I make it so that double-clicking the script defaults to opening the script in powershell?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191386/how-can-i-get-batch-files-to-run-through-the-new-windows-terminal

Comment: take a look at the Answers to this Question >>> Is there a way to make a PowerShell script work by double clicking a .ps1 file? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-a-ps1-file/30358174#30358174

Comment: Try running `ftype Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "%1"` in cmd

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I want it to be universal and that doesn't work :(

Comment: @NekoMusume it says ```Access is denied.
Error occurred while processing: Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1.
```

Comment: Run it in administrator

Comment: @NekoMusume It works now, thank you. Is there a way I can pass arguments to the files?

Comment: From double-click? I don't think so.

Comment: @NekoMusume - the Answer given by `Neko Musume` is a variation of one of the Answers given in that link. [*grin*]

Comment: O I don't like the registry and most of it was the registry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ftype Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "%1"
```

In administrator cmd. `Ftype` changes double-click behavior of certain filetypes specified by the `assoc` cmd command.